# Possible to have the 'Part' section to always start on odd page number?

Tags: latex, lyx

Is it possible to always have the 'Part' section to start at an odd page number? So that if the part one section extends to page two, then part two automatically moves to page three. I'm using Lyx to create the Latex file.

EDIT: Just discovered that I have been using section instead of part. Have changed all the sections to part. Still the same issue.

Oerjan...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `twoside` document-class option does not take care of this problem, then the following surely will:

```
\let\originalpart=\part
\def\part{\cleardoublepage\originalpart}
```

Or you could just insert `\cleardoublepage` by hand.

Comment: Yes, I enabled the 'twoside', and it fixed it. Ended up with using the book document class and chapters. Together with the 'twoside' option it was ok.

Answer (score 1):

Part, for default, starts at an odd page and occupies the whole page. Chapters start on the next odd page (for books) and in the next page available (for reports).

Comment: I have no document class that is named 'default'.
I had to enable the 'twoside' option to get this to work.